# Appium + Android studio -> duplicate entry: com/thoughtworks/selenium/CommandProcessor.class

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

I am trying to run Appium on Android studio, There are the libraries i have use for my project

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile files('libs/testng-6.9.4.jar')
compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')
compile files('libs/java-client-3.2.0.jar')
compile files('libs/selenium-java-2.47.1.jar')
compile files('libs/selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar')
}
```

While running the code i get an error

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/thoughtworks/selenium/CommandProcessor.class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to include these dependencies like this:

```
compile 'org.testng:testng:6.9.10'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'io.appium:java-client:3.4.1'
compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.53.0'
compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:2.53.0'
```

Note: I have include the latest versions as of now.

If you want to use `jar` then it seems like that it hasn't been properly built. So try to do something like this:

1. Unzip the `jar` file. (Simply change `.jar` extension to `.zip`
2. This will remove the duplicate files.
3. Recreate the `jar` using `jar cf some_name.jar -C (path to unzipped folder) .` (Mind it, there is a dot in the end of command)
4. Use this regenerated `jar`

Comment: Thanks for your input. Now i get another error
 Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.class

Comment: @VinayJayaram, replace all `jar` dependencies with `gradle`

Comment: Tried compiling with your latest version now getting new error  Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: net/sf/cglib/beans/BeanCopier$BeanCopierKey.class

Comment: @VinayJayaram, again include this `compile 'cglib:cglib:3.2.2'` and remove `jar` from libs.

Comment: i have removed all jars and included compile 'cglib:cglib:3.2.2' still another error :-(   Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: net/sf/cglib/proxy/Mixin$Generator.class

Comment: @VinayJayaram, are sure you don't have any `jar` in `app` -> `libs` folder?

Comment: Yes libs folder is empty also this is what i have in gradle dependency dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'org.testng:testng:6.9.10'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'io.appium:java-client:3.4.1'
    compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.53.0'
    compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:2.53.0'
    compile 'cglib:cglib:3.2.2'
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109407/discussion-between-vinay-jayaram-and-rohit-arya).